# How to texture a cube so that each face has the same uv coordinates?

Tags: texturing, uv

I would like each face of a cube to have the same texture coordinates as each face will contain the same image. Therefore there will be no wasted space from storing a 'T' shaped image, instead of a square image.

I have attempted uv unwrap the cube and layer the islands on top of each other. However, I am unable to scale and align all of the faces to the full size of my square texture (image).

How can I fix this issue or is there a better carried out this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go to edit mode, select everything, hit U and choose reset!